# Error: Form submission failed and no error message returned from: contact.php

Tags: php, html, forms, contacts, contact-form

I am having this issue

My php code is

```
<?php
//Import PHPMailer classes into the global namespace
//These must be at the top of your script, not inside a function
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $name = $_POST["name"];
    $email = $_POST["email"];
    $subject = $_POST["subject"];
    $message = $_POST["message"];


//Load Composer's autoloader
require 'PHPMailer/Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'PHPMailer/SMTP.php';

//Create an instance; passing `true` enables exceptions
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);

try {
    //Server settings
    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;                      
    $mail->isSMTP();                                            
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.gmail.com';                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                                   
    $mail->Username   = 'test1@test.com';                     
    $mail->Password   = '000000000000';                               
    $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;            
    $mail->Port       = 587;                                    


    $mail->setFrom('test1@test.com', 'Contactform');
    $mail->addAddress('test2@test.com', 'website mail');  


    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
    $mail->Subject = "Sender Subject - $subject";
    $mail->Body    = "Sender Name - $name <br> Sender Email - $email <br> Sender Subject - $subject <br> Message - $message";

    $mail->send();
    echo "Your message has been sent. Thank you!";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo "Message could not be sent.";
}

}

?>
```

And My HTML Contact Form Code is

```
<div class="col-lg-8">
        <form action="contact.php" method="post" role="form" class="php-email-form">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group">
              <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Your Name" required>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 form-group mt-3 mt-md-0">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Your Email" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject" required>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group mt-3">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="message" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
          </div>
          <div class="my-3">
            <div class="loading">Loading</div>
            <div class="error-message">Message could not be sent.</div>
            <div class="sent-message">Your message has been sent. Thank you!</div>
          </div>
          <div class="text-center"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">Send Message</button></div>
        </form>
      </div>
```

The PHPMailer and contact.php file both are working correctly if i remove this code from contact.php

[image]

Which connects my html contact form and php file to send email it works correctly i mean It Only send sample email to email id but it is working.

And When add this code to link my HTML Contact form to Contact.php file it gives me this error

> Error: Form submission failed and no error message returned from: contact.php

Comment: Any errors in the php log on the server?

Comment: Are you using JavaScript code to submit the form?  If so, please could you share the relevant portion here

Comment: _"Error: Form submission failed and no error message returned from: contact.php"_ - that doesn't sound like any default error message, but it does not appear to have been created by any of the code you have shown us so far either. And that it says "no error message returned from" really rather makes it sound as if there was client-side JavaScript involved in handling this all.

Answer (score 0):

```
This is java script
```

/**
* PHP Email Form Validation - v3.6
* URL: https://bootstrapmade.com/php-email-form/
* Author: BootstrapMade.com
*/
(function () {
"use strict";

```
  let forms = document.querySelectorAll('.php-email-form');

  forms.forEach(function (e) {
    e.addEventListener('submit', function (event) {
      event.preventDefault();

      let thisForm = this;

      let action = thisForm.getAttribute('action');
      let recaptcha = thisForm.getAttribute('data-recaptcha-site-key');

      if (!action) {
        displayError(thisForm, 'The form action property is not set!');
        return;
      }
      thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.add('d-block');
      thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').classList.remove('d-block');
      thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.remove('d-block');

      let formData = new FormData(thisForm);

      if (recaptcha) {
        if (typeof grecaptcha !== "undefined") {
          grecaptcha.ready(function () {
            try {
              grecaptcha.execute(recaptcha, { action: 'php_email_form_submit' })
                .then(token => {
                  formData.set('recaptcha-response', token);
                  php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData);
                })
            } catch (error) {
              displayError(thisForm, error);
            }
          });
        } else {
          displayError(thisForm, 'The reCaptcha javascript API url is not loaded!')
        }
      } else {
        php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData);
      }
    });
  });

  function php_email_form_submit(thisForm, action, formData) {
    fetch(action, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: formData,
      headers: { 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest' }
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
          return response.text();
        } else {
          throw new Error(`${response.status} ${response.statusText} ${response.url}`);
        }
      })
      .then(data => {
        thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
        if (data.trim() == 'OK') {
          thisForm.querySelector('.sent-message').classList.add('d-block');
          thisForm.reset();
        } else {
          throw new Error(data ? data : 'Form submission failed and no error message returned from: ' + action);
        }
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        displayError(thisForm, error);
      });
  }

  function displayError(thisForm, error) {
    thisForm.querySelector('.loading').classList.remove('d-block');
    thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').innerHTML = error;
    thisForm.querySelector('.error-message').classList.add('d-block');
  }

})();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).